# Showing multiple errors while upgrading php-5.6 to 7.3 in centOS 6.9 (Final)

Tags: php, linux, command-line, centos, upgrade

I'm trying to upgrade my php version 5.6 to 7.3 on centOS 6.9.
[I follow this.](https://www.tecmint.com/install-php-7-in-centos-6/)

Everything works fine but i'm getting package errors while running following command-

> sudo yum install php php-common php-opcache php-mcrypt php-cli php-gd php-curl php-mysql

It keeps saying-

```
--> Processing Dependency: libxml2.so.2(LIBXML2_2.9.0)(64bit) for package: php-x ml-7.3.28-1.el7.remi.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: libzip5-1.7.3-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-safe)
Requires: liblzma.so.5()(64bit)
Error: Package: php-twig-1.35.3-1.el6.remi.5.6.x86_64 (@remi-php56)
Requires: php(api) = 20131106-64
Removing: php-common-5.6.40-23.el6.remi.x86_64 (@remi-php56)
php(api) = 20131106-64
Updated By: php-common-7.3.28-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-php73)
php(api) = 20180731-64
Available: php-common-5.3.3-49.el6.x86_64 (base)
php(api) = 20090626
Available: php-common-7.3.27-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-php73)
php(api) = 20180731-64
Error: Package: php-7.3.28-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-php73)
Requires: httpd-mmn = 20120211x8664
Installed: httpd-2.2.15-69.el6.centos.x86_64 (@base)
httpd-mmn = 20051115
Available: httpd-2.2.15-59.el6.centos.x86_64 (base)
httpd-mmn = 20051115
Available: httpd-2.2.15-60.el6.centos.4.x86_64 (updates)
httpd-mmn = 20051115
Available: httpd-2.2.15-60.el6.centos.5.x86_64 (updates)
httpd-mmn = 20051115
Available: httpd-2.2.15-60.el6.centos.6.x86_64 (updates)
httpd-mmn = 20051115
Error: Package: php-xml-7.3.28-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-php73)
Requires: libxml2.so.2(LIBXML2_2.9.0)(64bit)
Error: Package: libzip5-1.7.3-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-safe)
Requires: liblzma.so.5(XZ_5.0)(64bit)
Error: Package: php-7.3.28-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-php73)
Requires: libcrypto.so.10(OPENSSL_1.0.2)(64bit)
Error: Package: php-cli-7.3.28-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-php73)
Requires: libcrypto.so.10(OPENSSL_1.0.2)(64bit)
Error: Package: php-gd-7.3.28-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-php73)
Requires: libpng15.so.15()(64bit)
Error: Package: php-gmp-7.3.28-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-php73)
Requires: libgmp.so.10()(64bit)
Error: Package: php-ldap-7.3.28-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-php73)
Requires: libsasl2.so.3()(64bit)
Error: Package: php-twig-1.35.3-1.el6.remi.5.6.x86_64 (@remi-php56)
Requires: php(zend-abi) = 20131226-64
Removing: php-common-5.6.40-23.el6.remi.x86_64 (@remi-php56)
php(zend-abi) = 20131226-64
Updated By: php-common-7.3.28-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-php73)
php(zend-abi) = 20180731-64
Available: php-common-5.3.3-49.el6.x86_64 (base)
php(zend-abi) = 20090626
Available: php-common-7.3.27-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-php73)
php(zend-abi) = 20180731-64
You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
** Found 1 pre-existing rpmdb problem(s), 'yum check' output follows:
glibc-utils-2.17-55.el6.x86_64 has missing requires of libgd.so.2()(64bit)
```

Comment: Looks like your missing some dependencies. Did you try to search on the errors you get?

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your response. yes i searched for solution and tried many things but  at the end same error is displaying. I just want to upgrade php on server. 
Is it possible that i didn't remove the php5.6 and i'm directly upgrading the php7.3 dependencies. so it's creating conflict? Like in ubuntu we can download multiple php. centOs is new thing for me

Answer (score 0):

1/ **CentOS 6 is dead** since november 2020

I heartily recommend to use a supported version.

2/ You are trying to install **el7** packages (so for CentOS 7) with **el6** packages

This cannot work.

3/ you need the right **repository configuration** files which are provided by

- [remi-release for el6](https://rpms.remirepo.net/enterprise/remi-release-6.rpm)

BTW, the "remi" repository is closed, and won't receive any update, as EPEL

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your response.. yes by mistake I added the el7 package. But i removed it and then i install el6 package.
Is it possible that i didn't remove the php5.6 and i'm directly upgrading the php7.3 dependencies. so it's creating conflict? I'm worked on ubuntu but centos is new thing for me.

Comment: "yum clean all" may help